# proving that the differences of squares of hyperbolic sin/cos is an integer.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

The hyperbolic sine and cosine are defined as following:

$\sinh(x)=\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$

$\cosh(x)=\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$

How do I show that their differences of squares are always an integer for all real numbers x?

hint appreciated!

Comment: You meant $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x$? Well, $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1\implies\sinh^2x-\cosh^2x=-1$, it's either $1$ or $-1$. If you're trying to prove that, just square it, expand it, and you'll get that result.

Comment: If it were more widely taught that these hyperbolic functions were connected to the geometry of the unit hyperbola  $ \ x^2 - y^2  =  1 \ $ , in the same way that the (circular) trig functions were related to the unit circle, it would be clear without calculation that $ \ \cosh^2 t - \sinh^2 t = 1 \ $ .

Answer (score 2):

Of course, there is the identity listed in the comments.  But, for fun, let's see what we can do without that:

$$\cosh^2(x) = \frac{(e^{x}+e^{-x})^2}{4} = \frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}+2e^0}{4}$$

$$\sinh^2(x) = \frac{(e^{x}-e^{-x})^2}{4} = \frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}-2e^0}{4}$$

So:
$$\begin{align}\require{cancel}
\sinh^2(x) - \cosh^2(x) &= \frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}-2}{4} - \frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}+2}{4}\\
&=\frac{\cancel{e^{2x}}+e^{-2x}-2 - \cancel{e^{2x}}-e^{-2x}-2}{4}\\
&=\frac{\cancel{e^{-2x}}-2 -\cancel{e^{-2x}}-2}{4}\\
&=\frac{-2 -2}{4}\\
&=\frac{-4}{4}\\
&=-1\\
\end{align}$$

To prove for the other difference, we don't have to do near as much algebra:
$$\begin{align}
\cosh^2(x) - \sinh^2(x) &= -(\sinh^2(x) - \cosh^2(x)) \\
&= - (-1) \\
&= 1
\end{align}$$

As $1$ and $-1$ are integers, we have proven what we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that that $$\begin{align}\cos iz&=\cosh z\\\sin iz&=i\sinh z\end{align}$$

Since $i^2=-1$, and $\cos^2z+\sin^2z=1$, we get that $$\cosh^2z-\sinh^2z=1$$